# Xcode Navigation Bar "Bar Tint" Clear Color is black

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar

I'm attempting to achieve an effect where the navigation bar has the "transparent blurry" effect. I've been able to achieve the desired effect with one problem. The navigation bar is a "black transparent" color. I'm looking for it to be a "white transparent" color. Here's an image of the current output:

[image: screenshot of the black navigation bar]

I've done a bunch of googling on the topic, and I can only find solutions that make the navigation bar completely transparent, or remove the transparency effect altogether.

Here is a screen shot of my storyboard settings for the navigation bar:

[image: Interface Builder - Settings for the navigation bar]

No matter how I modify these settings, the only way I can get the desired transparent blur effect is with it being "black transparent". Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default clear color is black with 0% opacity. Change the tint color of the navigation bar to **white**.

The opacity of the color does not matter in this case. You can test this by setting the tint color to black and comparing it with the results with black color with a different opacity.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Just to make sure we're on the same page, you want me to change the "background color" of the "view" section to white?

This change has no effect on the navigation bar color. It is still the transparent black color. Perhaps you were referring to the "bar tint" color?

Comment: @AlexRitter Sorry, I meant to write "tint color", thanks for notifying me. I updated my answer as well.

Comment: no problem. I made the change you suggested, and it seems that my mac monitor settings are such that I can barely tell the difference when it's white transparent. However I took a screen shot and loaded it up on another monitor. The effect is there. Is there any way to modify the opacity value of this transparent effect?

Comment: Oh well. thanks for pointing out that the effect was indeed happening.